# What is the ZF2 equivalent of the quoteInto() method of ZF1?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, quote

In Zend Framework 1 there is a quoteinto method for database adapter that can be used to quote sql statements.

I would like to know its equivalent in Zend Framework 2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `quoteInto()` method was removed with the introduction of the new `Zend\Db` in ZF 2.0. And there is no equivalent that has exactly the same behaviour.

In ZF2 there is the `quoteValue()` method. This method takes one value as a parameter, and then quotes the value so you can safely put it into an SQL query as a value.

However, you could use `quoteValue()` to replicate the behaviour of the ZF1 `quoteInto()` method. You could simply take the code of the `quoteInto()` method from [ZF1](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php), and apply the `quoteValue()` method from the platform object in ZF2 to it:

```
// modified quoteInto() function for ZF2
function quoteInto($text, $value, $platform, $count = null)
{
    if ($count === null) {
        return str_replace('?', $platform->quoteValue($value), $text);
    } else {
        while ($count > 0) {
            if (strpos($text, '?') !== false) {
                $text = substr_replace($text, $platform->quoteValue($value), strpos($text, '?'), 1);
            }
            --$count;
        }
        return $text;
    }
}
```

There are some differences. ZF1 has a `$type` parameter, but because of the way ZF2 works with these things, the type parameter doesn't make much sense. And there is a `$platform` parameter, because this method has a dependency on the platform for the `quoteValue()` method.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting a SQL statement is the old and potentially insecure way to do it. You should use prepared statements which have much better protection against SQL injection. I would use one of the PDO drivers [listed here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.db.adapter.html) (depending on your database) and follow some of the examples below that which use prepared queries.

Answer (score 0):

it's still there (kinda), check out `zf2 / library / Zend / Db / Adapter / Platform /your DB adapter` I found about 6 different `quote()` methods available in the [MySql variant](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Platform/Mysql.php). I think however that `quoteValue()` has replaced the default `quoteInto()` we're all used to.

[**EDIT**]
[Using the platform object](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.db.adapter.html#using-the-platform-object) will provide some direction but I think that most of the time the new [SQL](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.db.sql.html) classes will just use the platform api to do the quoting for us.
I'm still getting to know this myself so I'm not real sure about anything.

Comment: `quoteInto` takes two parameters: the string and the replaced value but `quoteValue` only takes 1 parameter. How should i use it?